# jQuery clone() problem

Tags: jquery, clone

```
<script>
function _addcategory() {
    $("#category_div").clone().insertAfter($("#category_div"));
}
</script>
<label for="category">Category</label>
<div id="category_div" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
<select id="category" name="category[]">
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="3">Item 1</option>
<option value="4">Item 2</option>
<option value="1">Item 3</option>
</select><script>document.write("<input id=\"addrow\" onclick=\"_addcategory();\" style=\"margin-left:5px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"+\" />");</script>
</div>
```

When I clicked on the button, the page turned blank except the button instead of cloning it. Is this a bug or my mistake? I've spent hours Googling but couldn't find a solution. Anyone know why?

Comment: why is the `input` button written in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write). Don't.

---

There are a lot of other problems with your code, as well. Here's how to make it work:

#### HTML

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<div class="category_div" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <select id="category" name="category[]">
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="3">Item 1</option>
        <option value="4">Item 2</option>
        <option value="1">Item 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<input id="addrow" style="margin-left:5px;" type="button" value="+" />
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    function _addCategory() {
        var $categoryDiv = $('div.category_div').last();
        $categoryDiv.clone().insertAfter($categoryDiv);
    }

    $('#addrow').click(_addCategory);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/zYEUY/

#### Notes

- `document.write()`: **[just don't use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/)**
- Element IDs must be unique. The quick solution is to change `id="category_div"` to `class="category_div"` and alter the JS accordingly.
- You're already using jQuery, so there's no excuse for not writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).
- Incorrect capitalization: your original code used `_addcategory` instead of `_addCategory`, so the `onclick` callback was `undefined`.